# How to render content of CALayer and sync with it in real-time

Tags: swiftui, uikit, core-graphics, calayer, metal

I'm creating a backdrop layer.

### I can

- find the correct layer that needs to be re-rendered in real-time.
- render these layers by using `layer.render(in: context)`.
- update capture by using `CADisplayLink` in real-time.

### But

Imagine I have a `ScrollView`, when user scrolls the view, the rendered content is one-frame behind the underlying view. Making the experience terrible.

### Screenshots

[image: gif]

[image: screenshot-of-the-problem]

### Code

```swift
TimelineView(.animation) { timeline in
    Canvas { context, size in
        let _ = timeline.date // Update content with DisplayLink.
        context.withCGContext { cgContext in
            for layer in renderer.backdropLayers {
                layer.render(in: cgContext)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I improve the rendering process?

> I know there is a private class called `CABackdropLayer` available to use. But I'm doing a SwiftUI App. Ideally, I can create a backdrop effect view and apply custom Shader to it.

You can check out my [post](https://x.com/LiYanan2004/status/1762384325612273957?s=20) on Twitter (or X) for what I'm building now.